# A chunk of my footer disappears from page

Tags: html, css

My footer when full screen adds space to the right and when i use for example mobile view a chunk of my footer disappears. I just want it to stay at the bottom and not cover any content. Even when it shrinks to mobile view.

```css
[![De red line is the extra space im talking about][1]][1]
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
  padding-right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  border-top: 4px solid #F2D380;
  overflow: auto;
}

#footer a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="row text-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-2 ">
      <a href="#"> Company Information </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <a href="#"> Privacy Policy and User Agreement </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <a href="about.html"> About </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <a href="about.html"> ©2019 Copyright claim </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/linkedin.png" class=" socialIcon">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/instagram.png" class=" socialIcon">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/facebook.png" class=" socialIcon">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/youtube.png" class="socialIcon">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe your content becomes more than `2.5rem` because of split lines?

Answer (score 1):

So the issue of why the space is added and it covers content is because of the absolute positioning. If you do not want it to cover content you have a couple options. Set the content wrapper to a set height and the footer to the rest of that height so the footer stays visible at the bottom and wont cover content.

If you just want it to act as a footer and be at the bottom on mobile I would just set it to be position relative.

It is hard to envision what you are going for without other content on the page.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying `height: 2.5rem`, you have given the footer a fixed height and it won't scale according to the content you have provided in it. Try `height: auto`, or `height: max-content`, because it seems your content is larger than the footer itself.
Also put `margin: 0` to ensure no space is added around it

Comment: margin: 0; doesn't remove the extra space. The rest  is fixed.

Comment: I've tested it and it works fine even on mobile view ... no spacing at all around it, could you share a screenshot of how it appears on your mobile view

Comment: So I've just noticed that you're using ```row``` and ```col-lg-2``` for class names, meaning you are using bootstrap, correct me if I'm wrong. So, your footer has 5 ```col-lg-2``` columns that means they span up to a total width of 10 columns, but bootstrap divides into ```12``` columns, so there is some unused "2-span" column and that's probably why there is space. I didn't use bootstrap for my snippet and it works fine.

Comment: I changed that but the problem you see on the picture (if the picture is not clear plz let me know) is still there :(.

Comment: The picture is clear but I just can't figure out the solution for that, but here's another thought ... The ```footer``` is clearly the container since it's enclosing the row and columns, so it should have the class ```container```, and if that doesn't work, change to ```container-fluid```, which spans full width ... Another possible problem is that you have only defined ```col-lg-"number"``` for large screens, you might wanna define also for other screens e.g: ```col-"number"``` for mobile screens, ```col-md-"number"``` for tablets and so on. it could also because of images which leave padding

Comment: Also, try running it without bootstrap and see how it turns out, if it is still the same, its definitely the images, I've ever run into such a situation where a div with an image leaves a margin relative to the next div, here's a possible fix: [Mysterious 4px margin around images](http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/09/The-mysterious-4px-gap-in-between-images/) ... A quick fix is to apply ```display: block``` to the images which by default have ```display: inline-block``` that makes them behave in such a way.